# WebMatrix - How do I define initial variable to hold db.query() return results without going out of scope or null type exception error?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, razor, webmatrix

I need to display results based on user selection from a drop down menu. The menu itself is dynamically populated with "jobquery".

I wrote the following code:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("database");
    String jobquery = "select description from match_jobs";
    IEnumerable<dynamic> data = null;
    var grid = new WebGrid(data, canPage: false);  

if(IsPost)
   {
    var description = Request["job"];
    String sql = "select top 30 * from match_@0_output";
    data = db.Query(sql, description); 
    }
}
```

Then in html, I have

```
        <div id="dynamic">
        Select Job
        <form name = "search" method="post">
        <select name="job">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Job</option>
        @foreach (var row in db.Query(jobquery))
        {
            <option value="@Request["job"]">@row.description</option>
        }
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="@Request["job"]"/>    
        </form> 
        </div>
```

The drop down menu worked fine. However, I am unable to call
@grid.GetHtml(); -> A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.

I tried

```
    </tr>
    @foreach (var row in data)
    {<tr>
        <td>@row.columnname</td>
     </tr>
    }
```

Didn't work either. -> NullOperation Exception

I Googled all week and conducted loads of failed experiments. At my wit's end now; expert help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

In the first section of your code, you declare a variable for your data, but you don't query the database at all. I'm not completely clear what you are trying to do but if you want to populate the grid with data, you should query the database:

```
var db = Database.Open("database");
var jobquery = "select description from match_jobs";
var data = db.Query(jobquery);
var grid = new WebGrid(data, canPage: false);
```

Then in your "html", you don't need to query the database again - you can re-use the variable that already holds the data:

```
<div id="dynamic">
Select Job
<form name = "search" method="post">
<select name="job">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select Job</option>
@foreach (var row in data)
{
    <option value="@Request["job"]">@row.description</option>
}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="@Request["job"]"/>    
</form> 
</div>
```

The section of code in the `IsPost` condition makes no sense at all. You query the database and then call `Response.Redirect` - telling the browser to request a different page. All values in the current page - including the data you have just retrieved are discarded when you do this.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you for your response. I am querying a table (job) to generate a drop down list. Then, from the job list, user select a value. Based on user input, the grid gets populated.